# Spy actual method call, not able to stub the calls in the actual method by mocking

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spy

I've got an existing class for which I need to write unit test cases using Junit and Mockito.
The method I'm trying to test calls a method of another class which returns nothing but populates a Map which is passed as a parameter to the method call.
I'm using @Spy to call the actual method as I want to get the Map in my test method for further usage. But the actual method that is being called has dependency on another Utility class whose behavior I'm trying to mock using @Mock but the Utility class is not being mocked and I'm getting an NPE.
Can someone please help with what needs to be done in this case.

```
public class MyClass {
  
  public Response method() {//Method to be tested
    Map<String, Object> mapToBePopulated = new HashMap<>();
    supportClass.populateMap(mapToBePopulated);
  }
}
public class SupportClass {
  @Autowired
  UtilityClass utility;

  public void populateMap(Map<String, List<Object>> mapToBePopulated) {
    //populateMap
    utility.doSomething(mapToBePopulated); //I'm mocking Utility class but when the debugger comes to this line the utility object is Null which throws the NPE.
  }
  //this method is being stubbed
  public Object doSomething(String one) {
  //some lines
  }
}
```

Edit: Added other methods that are part of the SupportClass which I'm stubbing so can't really use @InjectMocks here. Is there a way to avoid calling the actual method and still populate the Map?

Comment: It feels like you are rather trying to unit test SupportClass.populateMap instead of MyClass.method.
MyClass.method only responsability is to call supportClass.pomulateMap with the right map, that is all there is to test, you can use Mockito.verify to ensure the populateMap has been called with the right parameter

Comment: @Kurojin, I don't have a choice but to call the actual method as I want the Map to be populated  as it is used ahead in certain conditions and other method calls of MyClass which needs to be tested. As the map is always empty I'm not able to increase the coverage. Also, I can't really populate the Map in the test class as it is being initialized in the method itself before the call and the method returns nothing as well. Rest of the methods of the SupportClass are all being stubbed as they are returning something.

Comment: the ideal would be to make populateMap return a result and not mutate data as a side effect.
The problem with calling real implementations of classes outside your test scope, is that if SupportClass has problems, it will propagate to your MyClass.

Comment: I completely agree with what you're saying but unfortunately I'm not allowed to make changes to any class. The changes that are required needs to be documented to be taken up later in the year. Main focus is to improve coverage to the legacy code which is very poorly designed so I'm stuck with this without a solution and coverage below 85% is unacceptable. Without a solution for this my coverage just cannot go over 60%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a fake support class that extends the real one for the test purpose.
Override the populateMap method with a predictible logic that suits your test case.
In your test, pass the fake support class instead of the real one

Comment: thanks a lot. This worked. Not sure why I didn't think about this and was thinking more on the lines of mocking. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject mocks to the spied object.

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    private MyClass myClass;

    @Mock
    private UtilityClass utilityClassMock;

    @InjectMocks
    private SupportClass supportClassSpy;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        supportClassSpy = Mockito.spy(new SupportClass());
        myClass = new MyClass(supportClassSpy);
    }

    @Test
    public void yourTest() {
        // ...
    }

}
```

See [Injecting a Mock Into a Spy](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations#injecting-a-mock-into-spy)

Comment: I'm sorry I missed out on adding a couple of points. The supportClass has other methods that I'm stubbing using doReturn as I'm using a spy. But in the case mentioned above I want to call the actual method as I want the Map to be populated. Inject mocks will call all the actual methods of that class so can't really use that? Is there a way to populate the Map without calling the actual method?